# How to fix perl error Test::More dependency failed?

Tags: linux, updates, perl, cpanel

Upgrading cpanel, I'm getting the following error during install (from the cpanel logfile):

```
[Starting localperl]
! Installing Test::More failed. See /root/.cpanm/work/1470678270.4225/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'Test::More' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for Try-Tiny-0.24.
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'Test::More' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for HTTP-Tiny-0.058.
! Couldn't find module or a distribution Test::More
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'Test::More' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for Try-Tiny-0.24.
! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'Test::More' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for HTTP-Tiny-0.058.
Cannot bootstrap Try::Tiny and HTTP::Tiny on /usr/bin/perl at /usr/local/cpanel/bin/install_locallib_loginprofile line 96.
```

Additionally, this error (in same logfile):

```
==> Found dependencies: Test::More
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                |
|   ERROR! cPanel cannot bootstrap Try::Tiny and HTTP::Tiny to /usr/bin/perl.    |
|   Most cPanel scripts which use /usr/bin/perl (including /scripts/easyapache)  |
|   will not function correctly until you resolve this.                          |
|                                                                                |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I don't know how to fix this issue. I tried uninstalling perl to reinstall but doing so would wipe out half my system along with it so that isn't an option:

```
================================================================================================================
 Package                                        Arch         Version                      Repository       Size
================================================================================================================
Removing:
 perl                                           x86_64       4:5.10.1-141.el6_7.1         @updates         34 M
Removing for dependencies:
 autoconf                                       noarch       2.63-5.1.el6                 @base           2.5 M
 automake                                       noarch       1.11.1-4.el6                 @base           1.5 M
 cpanel-git                                     x86_64       2.9.2-1.cp1158               installed        31 M
 cpanel-perl-522-Dist-Zilla-Plugin-Git          x86_64       2.036-1.cp1156               installed        64 k
 cpanel-perl-522-Dist-Zilla-Plugin-GitHub       x86_64       0.41-1.cp1156                installed        54 k
 cpanel-perl-522-Git-Repository                 x86_64       1.315-1.cp1156               installed        57 k
 cpanel-perl-522-Git-Wrapper                    x86_64       0.045-1.cp1156               installed        33 k
 cpanel-php56                                   x86_64       5.6.20-10.cp1158             installed        51 M
 cpanel-php56-Auth-SASL                         noarch       1.0.6-2.cp1158               installed        51 k
 cpanel-php56-Cache                             noarch       1.5.6-2.cp1158               installed       158 k
 cpanel-php56-Console-Color                     noarch       1.0.3-2.cp1158               installed        18 k
 cpanel-php56-Console-Table                     noarch       1.1.5-2.cp1158               installed        42 k
 cpanel-php56-DB                                noarch       1.7.14-2.cp1158              installed       690 k
 cpanel-php56-Date                              noarch       1.4.7-2.cp1158               installed       402 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays                     noarch       0.21.8-2.cp1158              installed       248 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Australia           noarch       0.2.1-2.cp1158               installed        16 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Austria             noarch       0.1.5-2.cp1158               installed        31 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Brazil              noarch       0.1.2-2.cp1158               installed        18 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Croatia             noarch       0.1.1-2.cp1158               installed       6.5 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Czech               noarch       0.1.0-2.cp1158               installed        14 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Denmark             noarch       0.1.3-2.cp1158               installed        19 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-EnglandWales        noarch       0.1.5-2.cp1158               installed        16 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Finland             noarch       0.1.2-2.cp1158               installed        17 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Germany             noarch       0.1.2-2.cp1158               installed       102 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Iceland             noarch       0.1.2-2.cp1158               installed        26 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Ireland             noarch       0.1.3-2.cp1158               installed        22 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Italy               noarch       0.1.1-2.cp1158               installed        21 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Japan               noarch       0.1.2-2.cp1158               installed        88 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Netherlands         noarch       0.1.3-2.cp1158               installed        24 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Norway              noarch       0.1.2-2.cp1158               installed        16 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-PHPdotNet           noarch       0.1.2-2.cp1158               installed        20 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Portugal            noarch       0.1.0-2.cp1158               installed        18 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Romania             noarch       0.1.2-2.cp1158               installed        12 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Russia              noarch       0.1.0-2.cp1158               installed        26 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-SanMarino           noarch       0.1.1-2.cp1158               installed       9.9 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Serbia              noarch       0.1.0-2.cp1158               installed       8.2 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Slovenia            noarch       0.1.2-2.cp1158               installed        18 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Spain               noarch       0.1.3-2.cp1158               installed       9.3 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Sweden              noarch       0.1.3-2.cp1158               installed        35 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Turkey              noarch       0.1.1-2.cp1158               installed        13 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-UNO                 noarch       0.1.3-2.cp1158               installed        97 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-USA                 noarch       0.1.1-2.cp1158               installed        28 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Ukraine             noarch       0.1.2-2.cp1158               installed        14 k
 cpanel-php56-Date-Holidays-Venezuela           noarch       0.1.1-2.cp1158               installed       7.0 k
 cpanel-php56-File                              noarch       1.4.1-2.cp1158               installed        36 k
 cpanel-php56-File-Find                         noarch       1.3.2-2.cp1158               installed        34 k
 cpanel-php56-File-Fstab                        noarch       2.0.3-2.cp1158               installed        30 k
 cpanel-php56-HTML-Template-IT                  noarch       1.3.0-2.cp1158               installed       107 k
 cpanel-php56-HTTP                              noarch       1.4.1-2.cp1158               installed        38 k
 cpanel-php56-HTTP-Request                      noarch       1.4.4-2.cp1158               installed        73 k
 cpanel-php56-HTTP-WebDAV-Server                noarch       1.0.0RC8-2.cp1158            installed       143 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Alarm                       noarch       2.2.7-1.cp1158               installed       228 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Argv                        noarch       2.0.12-1.cp1158              installed       365 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Auth                        noarch       2.1.12-1.cp1158              installed       336 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Autoloader                  noarch       2.1.2-1.cp1158               installed        58 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Browser                     noarch       2.0.12-1.cp1158              installed       219 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Cache                       noarch       2.5.3-1.cp1158               installed       137 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Cli                         noarch       2.0.6-2.cp1158               installed       135 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Compress                    noarch       2.1.5-1.cp1158               installed       3.0 M
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Compress-Fast               noarch       1.1.1-1.cp1158               installed        45 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Constraint                  noarch       2.0.3-1.cp1158               installed        23 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Controller                  noarch       2.0.4-1.cp1158               installed        50 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Core                        noarch       2.23.0-1.cp1158              installed       7.2 M
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Crypt                       noarch       2.7.3-1.cp1158               installed       872 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Crypt-Blowfish              noarch       1.1.1-1.cp1158               installed        87 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Css-Parser                  noarch       1.0.10-1.cp1158              installed       324 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-CssMinify                   noarch       1.0.2-2.cp1158               installed        35 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Data                        noarch       2.1.4-1.cp1158               installed       242 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Date                        noarch       2.3.0-1.cp1158               installed       439 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Date-Parser                 noarch       2.0.5-1.cp1158               installed       158 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Dav                         noarch       1.1.3-1.cp1158               installed       1.0 M
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Db                          noarch       2.3.1-1.cp1158               installed       596 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Editor                      noarch       2.0.4-2.cp1158               installed       2.5 M
 cpanel-php56-Horde-ElasticSearch               noarch       1.0.2-2.cp1158               installed        16 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Exception                   noarch       2.0.8-1.cp1158               installed       131 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Feed                        noarch       2.0.1-2.cp1158               installed       5.9 M
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Form                        noarch       2.0.13-1.cp1158              installed       1.1 M
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Group                       noarch       2.1.1-1.cp1158               installed       128 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-HashTable                   noarch       1.2.4-1.cp1158               installed        66 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-History                     noarch       2.3.6-1.cp1158               installed       138 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Http                        noarch       2.1.6-1.cp1158               installed        81 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Icalendar                   noarch       2.1.4-1.cp1158               installed       507 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Idna                        noarch       1.0.4-1.cp1158               installed        23 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Image                       noarch       2.3.5-1.cp1158               installed       2.4 M
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Imap-Client                 noarch       2.29.6-1.cp1158              installed       1.4 M
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Imsp                        noarch       2.0.5-2.cp1158               installed       188 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Injector                    noarch       2.0.5-1.cp1158               installed       121 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Itip                        noarch       2.1.2-1.cp1158               installed       260 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-JavascriptMinify            noarch       1.1.3-1.cp1158               installed        45 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Kolab-Format                noarch       2.0.4-2.cp1158               installed       452 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Kolab-Session               noarch       2.0.1-2.cp1158               installed       142 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-ListHeaders                 noarch       1.2.4-1.cp1158               installed        65 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Lock                        noarch       2.1.2-1.cp1158               installed        73 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Log                         noarch       2.2.0-1.cp1158               installed        88 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-LoginTasks                  noarch       2.0.7-1.cp1158               installed       169 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Mail                        noarch       2.6.3-1.cp1158               installed       209 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Mail-Autoconfig             noarch       1.0.3-1.cp1158               installed        75 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Mime                        noarch       2.9.5-1.cp1158               installed       749 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Mime-Viewer                 noarch       2.1.3-1.cp1158               installed       917 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Nls                         noarch       2.2.0-1.cp1158               installed       2.0 M
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Notification                noarch       2.0.4-1.cp1158               installed        98 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Oauth                       noarch       2.0.1-2.cp1158               installed        26 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Pack                        noarch       1.0.6-1.cp1158               installed        62 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Pdf                         noarch       2.0.3-2.cp1158               installed       269 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Perms                       noarch       2.1.7-1.cp1158               installed       223 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Prefs                       noarch       2.7.6-1.cp1158               installed       293 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Queue                       noarch       1.1.3-1.cp1158               installed        34 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Rdo                         noarch       2.0.5-1.cp1158               installed       140 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Role                        noarch       1.0.1-2.cp1158               installed        33 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Routes                      noarch       2.0.5-1.cp1158               installed       270 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Rpc                         noarch       2.1.7-1.cp1158               installed       214 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Secret                      noarch       2.0.6-1.cp1158               installed        47 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Serialize                   noarch       2.0.5-1.cp1158               installed        68 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Service-Facebook            noarch       2.0.5-2.cp1158               installed       179 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Service-Twitter             noarch       2.1.1-2.cp1158               installed        48 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-SessionHandler              noarch       2.2.7-1.cp1158               installed       119 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Share                       noarch       2.0.10-1.cp1158              installed       383 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Smtp                        noarch       1.9.3-1.cp1158               installed       137 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Socket-Client               noarch       2.1.1-1.cp1158               installed        39 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-SpellChecker                noarch       2.1.3-1.cp1158               installed        43 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Stream                      noarch       1.6.3-1.cp1158               installed        81 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Stream-Filter               noarch       2.0.4-1.cp1158               installed        48 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Stream-Wrapper              noarch       2.1.3-1.cp1158               installed        27 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Support                     noarch       2.1.5-1.cp1158               installed       125 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-SyncMl                      noarch       2.0.3-2.cp1158               installed       914 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Template                    noarch       2.0.3-1.cp1158               installed        49 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Text-Diff                   noarch       2.1.2-1.cp1158               installed       123 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Text-Filter                 noarch       2.3.4-1.cp1158               installed       279 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Text-Flowed                 noarch       2.0.3-1.cp1158               installed        48 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Timezone                    noarch       1.0.11-1.cp1158              installed       117 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Token                       noarch       2.0.9-1.cp1158               installed       175 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Translation                 noarch       2.2.1-1.cp1158               installed        64 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Tree                        noarch       2.0.4-2.cp1158               installed        77 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Url                         noarch       2.2.5-1.cp1158               installed        64 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Util                        noarch       2.5.7-1.cp1158               installed       166 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Vfs                         noarch       2.3.2-1.cp1158               installed       441 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-View                        noarch       2.0.6-1.cp1158               installed       217 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Xml-Element                 noarch       2.0.4-1.cp1158               installed        50 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Xml-Wbxml                   noarch       2.0.1-2.cp1158               installed       119 k
 cpanel-php56-Horde-Yaml                        noarch       2.0.2-2.cp1158               installed        85 k
 cpanel-php56-Log                               noarch       1.12.7-2.cp1158              installed       240 k
 cpanel-php56-MDB2                              noarch       2.4.1-2.cp1158               installed       724 k
 cpanel-php56-Mail                              noarch       1.2.0-2.cp1158               installed       105 k
 cpanel-php56-Mail-Mime                         noarch       1.8.3-2.cp1158               installed       145 k
 cpanel-php56-Net-DNS2                          noarch       1.4.1-2.cp1158               installed       637 k
 cpanel-php56-Net-FTP                           noarch       1.3.7-2.cp1158               installed       147 k
 cpanel-php56-Net-IMAP                          noarch       1.1.2-2.cp1158               installed       252 k
 cpanel-php56-Net-SMTP                          noarch       1.6.2-2.cp1158               installed        57 k
 cpanel-php56-Net-Sieve                         noarch       1.3.2-2.cp1158               installed       263 k
 cpanel-php56-Net-Socket                        noarch       1.0.14-2.cp1158              installed        22 k
 cpanel-php56-Net-URL                           noarch       1.0.15-2.cp1158              installed        26 k
 cpanel-php56-Net-UserAgent-Detect              noarch       2.5.2-2.cp1158               installed        58 k
 cpanel-php56-PEAR-Command-Packaging            noarch       0.3.0-2.cp1158               installed       140 k
 cpanel-php56-SOAP                              noarch       0.13.0-2.cp1158              installed       438 k
 cpanel-php56-Services-Weather                  noarch       1.4.7-2.cp1158               installed       295 k
 cpanel-php56-Text-Figlet                       noarch       1.0.2-2.cp1158               installed        54 k
 cpanel-php56-XML-Parser                        noarch       1.3.4-2.cp1158               installed        68 k
 cpanel-php56-XML-RPC                           noarch       1.5.5-2.cp1158               installed       137 k
 cpanel-php56-XML-SVG                           noarch       1.1.0-2.cp1158               installed        39 k
 cpanel-php56-XML-Serializer                    noarch       0.20.2-2.cp1158              installed       215 k
 cpanel-php56-content                           noarch       2.0.5-1.cp1158               installed       121 k

 ... (removed a few like horde, squirrelmail, etc. because it made this superuser post too long) ...

 gd-progs                                       x86_64       2.0.35-11.el6                @base            76 k
 gettext                                        x86_64       0.17-18.el6                  @base           6.1 M
 gettext-devel                                  x86_64       0.17-18.el6                  @base           621 k
 libtool                                        x86_64       2.2.6-15.5.el6               @base           1.9 M
 memcached                                      x86_64       1.4.4-3.el6                  @base           147 k
 perl-Archive-Extract                           x86_64       1:0.38-141.el6_7.1           @updates         52 k
 perl-Archive-Tar                               x86_64       1.58-141.el6_7.1             @updates        113 k
 perl-CGI                                       x86_64       3.51-141.el6_7.1             @updates        434 k
 perl-CPAN                                      x86_64       1.9402-141.el6_7.1           @updates        663 k
 perl-CPANPLUS                                  x86_64       0.88-141.el6_7.1             @updates        767 k
 perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib                         x86_64       1:2.021-141.el6_7.1          @updates        143 k
 perl-Compress-Zlib                             x86_64       2.021-141.el6_7.1            @updates         51 k
 perl-DBD-SQLite                                x86_64       1.27-3.el6                   @base           221 k
 perl-DBI                                       x86_64       1.609-4.el6                  @base           1.7 M
 perl-DBIx-Simple                               noarch       1.32-3.el6                   @base            62 k
 perl-Digest-SHA                                x86_64       1:5.47-141.el6_7.1           @updates         86 k
 perl-ExtUtils-CBuilder                         x86_64       1:0.27-141.el6_7.1           @updates         59 k
 perl-ExtUtils-Embed                            x86_64       1.28-141.el6_7.1             @updates         17 k
 perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker                        x86_64       6.55-141.el6_7.1             @updates        608 k
 perl-ExtUtils-ParseXS                          x86_64       1:2.2003.0-141.el6_7.1       @updates         61 k
 perl-File-Copy-Recursive                       noarch       0.38-4.el6                   @base            35 k
 perl-File-Fetch                                x86_64       0.26-141.el6_7.1             @updates         46 k
 perl-GD                                        x86_64       2.45-1.el5.rf                @rpmforge       585 k
 perl-GDGraph                                   noarch       1:1.44-7.el6                 @base           336 k
 perl-GDTextUtil                                noarch       0.86-15.el6                  @base            64 k
 perl-HTML-Parser                               x86_64       3.64-2.el6                   @base           221 k
 perl-HTML-Tagset                               noarch       3.20-4.el6                   @base            19 k
 perl-IO-Compress-Base                          x86_64       2.021-141.el6_7.1            @updates        135 k
 perl-IO-Compress-Bzip2                         x86_64       2.021-141.el6_7.1            @updates         59 k
 perl-IO-Compress-Zlib                          x86_64       2.021-141.el6_7.1            @updates        363 k
 perl-IO-Zlib                                   x86_64       1:1.09-141.el6_7.1           @updates         19 k
 perl-IPC-Cmd                                   x86_64       1:0.56-141.el6_7.1           @updates         57 k
 perl-Locale-Maketext-Simple                    x86_64       1:0.18-141.el6_7.1           @updates         13 k
 perl-Log-Message                               x86_64       1:0.02-141.el6_7.1           @updates         42 k
 perl-Log-Message-Simple                        noarch       0.06-1.el5.rf                @rpmforge        13 k
 perl-Module-Build                              noarch       1:0.3607-1.el5.rf            @rpmforge       684 k
 perl-Module-CoreList                           noarch       2.25-1.el5.rf                @rpmforge       645 k
 perl-Module-Load                               x86_64       1:0.16-141.el6_7.1           @updates        7.3 k
 perl-Module-Load-Conditional                   x86_64       0.30-141.el6_7.1             @updates         23 k
 perl-Module-Loaded                             x86_64       1:0.02-141.el6_7.1           @updates        5.9 k
 perl-Module-Pluggable                          x86_64       1:3.90-141.el6_7.1           @updates         30 k
 perl-Object-Accessor                           x86_64       1:0.34-141.el6_7.1           @updates         29 k
 perl-Package-Constants                         x86_64       1:0.02-141.el6_7.1           @updates        4.6 k
 perl-Params-Check                              x86_64       1:0.26-141.el6_7.1           @updates         25 k
 perl-Parse-CPAN-Meta                           x86_64       1:1.40-141.el6_7.1           @updates         13 k
 perl-Pod-Escapes                               x86_64       1:1.04-141.el6_7.1           @updates         21 k
 perl-Pod-Simple                                x86_64       1:3.13-141.el6_7.1           @updates        466 k
 perl-Term-UI                                   x86_64       0.20-141.el6_7.1             @updates         31 k
 perl-Test-Harness                              noarch       3.22-1.el5.rf                @rpmforge       589 k
 perl-Test-Simple                               noarch       0.98-1.el5.rf                @rpmforge       250 k
 perl-Time-HiRes                                x86_64       4:1.9721-141.el6_7.1         @updates         56 k
 perl-Time-Piece                                x86_64       1:1.20-1.el5.rf              @rpmforge       120 k
 perl-Try-Tiny                                  noarch       0.09-1.el5.rf                @rpmforge        22 k
 perl-URI                                       noarch       1.40-2.el6                   @base           250 k
 perl-core                                      x86_64       5.10.1-141.el6_7.1           @updates        0.0
 perl-devel                                     x86_64       4:5.10.1-141.el6_7.1         @updates        1.8 M
 perl-libs                                      x86_64       4:5.10.1-141.el6_7.1         @updates        1.4 M
 perl-libwww-perl                               noarch       5.833-3.el6                  @base           882 k
 perl-parent                                    x86_64       1:0.221-141.el6_7.1          @updates        5.7 k
 perl-version                                   x86_64       3:0.77-141.el6_7.1           @updates         51 k
 sharutils                                      x86_64       4.7-6.1.el6                  @base           617 k
 vim-enhanced                                   x86_64       2:7.4.629-5.el6              @base           2.2 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================================================
Remove      242 Package(s)

Installed size: 323 M
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

"um, NO this is not okay no I don't want to uninstall practiceally my whole system and take down my server!"

`yum reinstall perl` gives me an error also:

```
# yum reinstall perl
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Reinstall Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: denver.gaminghost.co
 * extras: mirror.n5tech.com
 * rpmforge: mirror.hmc.edu
 * updates: mirrors.xmission.com
Installed package 4:perl-5.10.1-141.el6_7.1.x86_64 (from updates) not available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

`yum install perl` gives me this:

```
# yum install perl

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: denver.gaminghost.co
 * extras: mirror.n5tech.com
 * rpmforge: mirror.hmc.edu
 * updates: mirrors.xmission.com
Nothing to do
```

However perl is listed in installed packages as seen above.

How do I fix this issue and get perl installed properly?

Answer (score 6):

Try to

`yum install perl-Test-Simple`

This should install your missing perl module `Test::More`

Comment: Thank you for the tip. However it gives the output `# yum install perl-Test-Simple
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.keystealth.org
 * extras: centos.unixheads.org
 * rpmforge: mirror.hmc.edu
 * updates: mirror.cs.uwp.edu
Nothing to do` when I run that.

Comment: Quick and simple—it worked!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check that `make` and `CPAN` perl packet manager are there in your system:

```
yum install make cpan
```

Then configure your perl with CPAN. Just enter `cpan` in the command prompt and answer `yes` to all interactive questions.

Then update you `cpan` manager:

```
#cpan install Bundle::CPAN
#cpan reload cpan
```

And now install packages of your interest:

```
#cpan install Test::More
```